# Getting "TypeError: connect.describeSecurityProfile is not a function" , even though I made sure that everything is similar to Amazon SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, async-await, runtime-error, amazon-connect

TypeError: connect.describeSecurityProfile is not a function
Getting the above-mentioned error when trying to code this. connect.describeUser(params).promise(); is working fine but the following code throws error.

```
let paramaters;
        paramaters = {
            InstanceId: "",
            SecurityProfileId: "",
        };
        console.log({ paramaters });
        let describeSG = await connect.describeSecurityProfile(paramaters).promise();
        console.log("describeSG", JSON.stringify(describeSG));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the v3 SDK you should instantiate `DescribeSecurityProfileCommand` and use the `send()` function of `ConnectClient` to execute it.  The `send()` function returns a promise, so you can use async `await`.  The following is a working example based on the docs that can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-connect/classes/describesecurityprofilecommand.html)

```
import { ConnectClient, DescribeSecurityProfileCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-connect";

const client = new ConnectClient({ region: "us-west-2" });

const params = {
  SecurityProfileId: "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  InstanceId: "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
};

const command = new DescribeSecurityProfileCommand(params);

const resp = await client.send(command);

console.log(resp);
```

Comment: why only this sdk is having issue? All other connect sdk and Ec2 sdk are calling in same way and working fine.

Comment: This seems like it may be a defect in the SDK, as I got the same result using the implementation in the original question. That code should work but does not, so I provided this answer as a working alternative.